# Convert Zend framework website language?

Tags: zend-framework, translation, multilingual, translate, zend-translate

Hello I am a newbie to Zend Framework. I want to convert a website constructed in English language using Zend Framework to Ukrainian language. 
Can anyone help me out what to do? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you website supports internationalization, so all UI strings can be localized via translate() helper and Zend_Translate.

If your website already has more than one language - in most cases you should not care about this step.

1. Extract all UI strings into translation resource file (Gettext .po, TMX, xliff, etc..)
2. Hire translator to perform actual translation for you, or do that on your own.
3. Deploy new resource to website and make sure the locale is getting recognized for your language (or do the manual language switch link)

Your question is very general and I'm not sure on which step you need an assistance. Generally localization into Ukrainian language should not have any special cases. Follow any of numerous HOWTOs on ZF website localization for any other languages you can find on the Internet.